# absolute width messing up all my divs in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on designing HTML page by looking at the image I have. It should exactly match with what I have in my image (in the link). I have got almost everything designed as that image but few things I am not able to make it work. Here is my [image link](https://s12.postimg.org/4xtgnby3h/0-nav-open.png) and I have to design HTML page exactly as it is.

And here is [my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2ahx6nq/22/) which I have designed by looking at the image.

It looks like I am having problem with absolute width because of which all my divs are getting messed up.

- I can see white space between `company-bio` div and `mission-statements` div which I am not able to remove somehow? And I don't understand why it is even coming.
- Also `northmanwild` div is going out of alignment as well.
- There is a lot of white space below `copy-rights` div at the end and that is also not matching with my image.

Also somehow all the alignments of my div looks ok on my browser on my laptop but when I made jsfiddle, it looks weird and it goes haywire. It doesn't matches with what I have in my image link. So maybe what I have won't work with multiple browsers or multiple resolution.

Here is my css for `company-bio`:

```
body .company-bio {
    position: relative;
    top: -42px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 131px;
    /*Added Just now */
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: url("https://s30.postimg.org/l04wudgs1/grey-bar.png");
    padding-left: 140px;
    padding-right: 155px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Adelle PE";
}
```

What is wrong I am doing because of which my html is getting messed up here? What I am supposed to do to solve this absolute width problem so that my html works fine anywhere without alignment getting messed up.

**Note:** I still need to work on left navigation text which I haven't done that yet. As of now I am trying to fix all the alignment issues which I am having because of absolute width I believe is happening.

Comment: You have already posted this question half an hour ago.

Comment: Yeah it was not clear I believe and it got closed so opened a new one with more clarity.

Comment: The gap between `company-bio` and `mission-statements` comes from `top: -42px;` on `company-bio`. You shifted it upwards.

Comment: @JeremyThille I see.. I was reading more about absolute width and I think that is causing this issue. Since I am relatively new to designing world what is the right way to fix all this without using absolute positioning so that it works fine in multiple browsers or systems?

Comment: Well that's too vast a subject to be trated in a comment or even in an answer. This question is very broad, it's all about how to develop a website. CSS positioning requires a lot of practice, but just start with _not_ using absolute positioning for your general layout :) Just pile up divs

Comment: I know that but what I am trying to say is there should be a better way to fix all these div alignments and that's how I will learn as well.

Comment: There are also countless CSS frameworks out there with efficient responsive grid systems (the most famous being Bootstrap), no need to reinvent the wheel.